# Move files from main to branch, then delete from main

Tags: git

I have a repository where I started a task as a Dash app with Plotly graphs and then decided to build it a completely different way for now, after committing the Dash app files to main. So now I have a bunch of Dash app related files along with the files I actually need. I don't want to delete those files - I'd like to come back to that method later - but if I'm going to finish this project without them, I don't want them in the main branch.

Is there a way to delete files from the main branch but keep them in a different branch if that branch doesn't currently exist and the files currently exist in the main branch?

Answer (score -1):

Try these commands:

```bash
git checkout main-branch # just to be sure you are on main-branch
git checkout -b main-branch-backup # now you have all commits (like a copy) from main-branch here
git log # verify in the commit log history, all commits will be here
git checkout main-branch # move back to main-branch
    
git checkout -b test-removing # like main-branch-backup but here you remove things
# assume you need to remove the last two commits you can do like so or change the number from the next line
git reset --hard HEAD~2 
    
# if it worked you can do the same on main-branch, if it did not work
# as you expected, remove the branch test-removing and start again
```